# Gap between patio and fence

Tags: fence, patio

I will be removing all of the leaves and debris from the gap between the cement patio and the wire fence in my garden and was wondering what I could fill the gap with? I plan on erecting a shad in the patio area and would like to fill the gap with something that is sturdy, any ideas?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JPgA.jpg

Comment: There seems to be a sapling of some sort growing in that patch which looks like it might be reasonably tall already, are you removing that? Will the shed you erect mean that area is in total shade afterwards? Does the wire fence belong to you or to your neighbour?

Comment: I will be removing it yes. The area will be in shade once the shed is erect. And the fence is indeed ours. Thanks!

Comment: How do you plan to permanently remove both the blackberry and the Hedera helix (English Ivy)?  Both of these are extremely difficult to eradicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that small area will be in total shade once the shed is erected. Given the small size of the area and the difficulty posed by a wire fence behind in terms of being able to weed it properly and keeping what's growing your side from going through it, I'd suggest laying a suitably sized patch of membrane to cover the soil and place decorative large pebbles or cobbles on top instead of trying to grow anything there. You could use gravel or pea shingle, but in my experience, cats tend to treat that as they do cat litter...

If you really want to try to grow something and you think there's sufficient daylight, then Campanula portenschlagiana (previously Campanula muralis) might do the trick - or Ajuga reptans, but both will spread under the wire fence.